# Stata using loop values sequentially

Tags: stata

I want to replace this code with a loop:

```
replace var1=1 if year > 1996 & st==5
replace var1=0 if year < 1996 & st==5
replace var1=1 if year > 1998 & st==6
replace var1=0 if year < 1998 & st==6
```

My data looks like this

```
st year var
5  1993
5  1996
5  1992
6  1991
6  1999`
```

I wrote a loop like this

```
    foreach st in 5 6}
    foreach yr in 1996 1998 }
   replace var1=1 if year>`yr' & state==`st'
   replace var1=0 if year<`yr' & state==`st'
}
}
```

However this loop does not produce results similar to the manual  method. I know I am making a stupid mistake.

EDIT:

To further clarify my actual code I wrote (without using loops) looks like below. I would like to use a loop or other simpler method to arrive at the same results:

```
gen policy=.
replace policy=1 if year>1996 & fipscode==5
replace policy=0 if year <1997 & fipscode==5

replace policy=1 if year>1995 & fipscode==6
replace policy=0 if year <1996 & fipscode==6

replace policy=1 if year>1997 & fipscode==9
replace policy=0 if year <1998 & fipscode==9

replace policy=1 if year>1997 & fipscode==15
replace policy=0 if year <1998 & fipscode==15

replace policy=1 if year>1992 & fipscode==16
replace policy=0 if year <1993 & fipscode==16

replace policy=1 if year>1996 & fipscode==31
replace policy=0 if year <1997 & fipscode==31

replace policy=1 if year>1997 & fipscode==32
replace policy=0 if year <1998 & fipscode==32

replace policy=1 if year>1996 & fipscode==39
replace policy=0 if year <1997 & fipscode==39

replace policy=1 if year>1997 & fipscode==40
replace policy=0 if year <1998 & fipscode==40

replace policy=1 if year>1992 & fipscode==54
replace policy=0 if year <1993 & fipscode==54
```

Comment: I've corrected a trivial slip confusing 6 and 7. I have left the main code segment in your question exactly as posted. Note that you need left brace `{` at the start of each loop, not right brace `}`.

Comment: Unfortunately it is difficult to see that this question could help anybody but the original poster. That explains my downvote.

Comment: The extra example (after EDIT:) is even harder work. It is best just to work backwards: which conditions should be coded 1 and which coded 0? There is usually then some much simpler way of coding the variables. The condition on `fipscode` would reduce to `if inlist(fipscode,5,6,9,15,16,31,32,39,40,54)` although there is a limit on the number of arguments that function will take, except that it seems that there are different definitions for different years. Sometimes a complicated set of definitions just means complicated code.

Comment: sorry for the inconvenience but i still don't understand how using inlist command can help me in this situation

Comment: `inlist()` is a function, not a command. It can help you in your more complicated example when the conditions on `year` are the same for different `fipscode`, as with 5, 31, 39. Then the statements can be combined.

Answer (score 0):

Try `forvalues` (I think this is efficient compared with `foreach`)

```
forvalues st=5/6{
    forvalues yr= 1996(2)1998{
        replace var1=1 if year>`yr' & state==`st'
        replace var1=0 if year<`yr' & state==`st'
    }
}
```

If you want to stick to `foreach`:

```
foreach st of numlist 5/6{
    foreach yr of numlist 1996(2)1998{
        replace var1=1 if year>`yr' & state==`st'
        replace var1=0 if year<`yr' & state==`st'
    }
}
```

Comment: Metrics is correct. `forvalues` is more efficient than `foreach` whenever there is an equivalent. That would be trivial here but is always worth noting.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you have some predetermined `year` matched against some predetermined `st`. In the example: 1996 with 5 and 1998 with 7. If not, then I misunderstood your problem. If so, you can loop over parallel lists:

```
clear
set more off

*----- example data -----

input ///
st year
5  1993
5  1996
5  1992
7  1991
7  1999
end

list

*----- what you want -----

gen var1 = .

local ylev 1996 1998
local slev 5 7
local n : word count `ylev'

forvalues i = 1/`n' {

    local y : word `i' of `ylev'
    local s : word `i' of `slev'

    replace var1 = 1 if year > `y' & st == `s'
    replace var1 = 0 if year < `y' & st == `s'

}

list
```

I'm curious as to why none of your conditions contains `=`, leaving out a case.

Comment: Good comment on ignoring the case of equality, which is a focus of my answer posted more or less simultaneously.

Answer (score 0):

The code may be more or less arbitrary code invented to learn technique, but the example really is strange. Even if the point is indeed just to learn technique, another lesson is to hand.

The variable `var1` must have been created beforehand for this to work. Experienced Stata users will take that as read, but the statement may help people learning Stata.

The testing of `year` against 1996 and then `year` against 1998 needs some analysis. It looks a little odd that values of 1996 and 1998 are themselves ignored each time around, as both `>` and `<` exclude `==`, but the code together does have implications for such values.

Setting aside first the question what `state` is, a pedestrian analysis shows that

1. Observations with `year` less than 1996 are coded 0 first time and remain 0 second time around the loop.
2. Observations with `year` equal to 1996 are ignored first time but coded 0 second time around the loop.
3. Observations with `year` equal to 1997 are coded 1 first time but reset to 0 second time.
4. Observations with `year` equal to 1998 are coded 1 first time but ignored second time.
5. Observations with `year` greater than 1998 are coded 1 first time and reset to 1 second time. (That includes any missing values on `year`.)

Bringing in the `state` variable, values other than 5 or 6 are ignored.

The whole double loop therefore collapses to a single statement

```
 replace var1 = year >= 1998 & inlist(state, 5, 6)
```

and six lines become one.

EDIT: The extra example appears to reduce to

```
 gen policy = .
 replace policy = (year>1996) if inlist(fipscode, 5, 31, 39)
 replace policy = (year>1995) if fipscode==6
 replace policy = (year>1997) if inlist(fipscode, 9, 15, 32, 40) 
 replace policy = (year>1992) if inlist(fipscode, 16, 54)
```

but it does not seem to allow a loop in any useful way.

Comment: To clarify i'm want the var1=1 if the two conditions are met. and i would want to have these 2 conditions in a loop. these two conditions will be coming from two lists. for example var1=1 if condition 1 in list (a)== var2 and condition 1 in list (b)= var=3. supposing that var 2 and 3 are already in the data set as two columns.

Comment: Sorry, that clarifies nothing for me without a worked example.  Unless you can find a fault in my logic, what else you want to do is another problem.